# MySQL db optimization and performance: 2 tables or 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, foreign-keys, innodb, split

Here are two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydatabase`.`members` (
`memberid` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`Time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PRIMARY KEY (memberid) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;


CREATE TABLE `mydatabase`.`orders` (
`orderid` INT(11)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`memberid` VARCHAR( 20 ),
`Time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
`info1` VARCHAR( 3200 ) NULL ,
`info2` DECIMAL (6,2) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid) ,
FOREIGN KEY (memberid) REFERENCES members(memberid)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

There are more tables in the db (so the answer to my question from experts could be probably different because of that).
Should I split table orders into 2 tables to increase the performance?
You see that table orders contains orderid, memberid and some more information about orders, that could be in the third separate table. Does it make sense to split table orders so table # 2 contains orderid and memberid, and third table contains orderid, Time, info1 and info2?

In most cases, when query selects information by **orderid**, it also doublechecks that information is for the proper user by checking "**WHERE memberid='abcde'**". So, only 1 user can see information from his order, but no one else. As result, I hope that keeping several additional columns **Time, info1, info2** (and some more columns about the order) in the same table **orders** is OK (else I have to use JOIN in queries to doublecheck **memberid** most of time anyway, and the queries become more complicated although tables are splitted). What's best for performance: split that tables -vs- using simpler queries?

BTW, am I creating these 2 tables properly according to performance rools and common sense (I'm asking about primary and foreign keys)?
Do you recommend to use INNODB instead of MYISAM? If yes, should I use **ENGINE = INNODB** instead of **ENGINE = MYISAM** ***for ALL tables*** in the db?

Thank you.

Comment: No, you should not put the member_id in a separate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB is the state-of-the-art engine from MySQL and the default engine. Use it every time except you've good reasons to not use InnoDB in a special case.

Do not disfigure your table layout for performance reasons. There are most probably other ways to solve performace problems - when you ever get into one ...

There are some reasons where I can think of where it makes sense, i.e. if you need [FULLTEXT-Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) on some column which is only available with MyISAM engine. Here it can make sense to split a table to separate the column with needed FULLTEXT-Index.

Comment: `memberid` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL (a primary key) , - it that what you mean saying FULL TEXT-Index? Does this mean MyISAM is a choice because of that for both tables? Thank you. Does all the rest look fine in my tables? Thank you.

Comment: No, you should use InnoDB for both. For Fulltext Index I'll add a link.